# How to work with Rcpp strings variables which could be NULL?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, stdstring, r-package

I am writing an R package + Rcpp code to work with an existing C++ library.

After going through the tutorials here: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/optional-null-function-arguments/ , I'm struggling with how to work with NULL and strings. I am confused that I cannot cast from type `Rcpp::Nullable<std::string>` to `std::string` (or equivalently `Rcpp::Nullable<Rcpp::String>` to `Rcpp::String`

Within C++, I am checking for whether the string (in C++) is empty or not. If the string is empty, I want to return NULL. If the string (in C++) is not empty, I want to return the string.

My example code is below, modifying the function `rcpp_hello_world()` provided by the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` for simplicity. My goal is to return within R a list (Rcpp::List) containing either a string, or NULL (if the string is empty).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List rcpp_hello_world() {

    // After calculations from external C++ library,
    // the variable 'mystring' will either empty (i.e. "") or populated (e.g. "helloworld")

    std::string mystring = "helloworld";  // string non-empty

    Rcpp::Nullable<std::string> result_string = R_NilValue;
    
    if (!mystring.empty()) {
        std::string result_string(mystring);
    }

    Rcpp::List z = List::create(result_string);

    return z ;
}
```

The resulting variable `result_string` in the above example should either be `NULL` or `"mystring"`---however, the above will always return `NULL`, which is not the desired behavior.

I then tried to see if I could even convert types between `Rcpp::Nullable<std::string>` and `std::string`:

```
std::string mystring = "helloworld";  
Rcpp::Nullable<std::string> result_string = R_NilValue;
std::string result_string(mystring);
```

This results in a compilation error:

```
error: redefinition of 'result_string' with a different type: 'std::string' 
(aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>') vs 'Rcpp::Nullable<std::string>' 
(aka 'Nullable<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char>>>')
```

Am I using the wrong data structures for this operation? Or is there a better way to work with strings if the value could be NULL?

Comment: Do all your input validation, including checking for null, before calling your C++ code

Comment: @HongOoi I am not checking for NULL. I am checking for whether the string is empty or not. If the string is empty, I want to return NULL. If the string is not empty, I want to return the string.

Comment: @HongOoi Please let me know if that makes sense---I cannot do this check within R; it's all within C++

Comment: Do all your input validation, including checking for an empty string, before calling your C++ code

Comment: @HongOoi 

Again, please let me know how to clarify the above SO question; there is some confusion here. 

I am parsing C++ output from the external C++ library. I *cannot* validate the input as you are describing; the variable `mystring` is a calculated output from the C++ library. If that variable is an empty string, the R list should return a NULL. If that variable is a non-empty string, the R list should return the string. 

Is this clear? `mystring` comes from C++

Comment: The error msg is clear enough. In your `if` statement, you have a `std::string` type `result_string` . Outside of the if statement (scope), the `std::string` object is destructed, and then you only have the `Rcpp` string, hence the NULL result. With this, I think you can work out the second half of the orignial question now.

Comment: Late to this but concur with other comments.  Also, the helper class `Nullable<>` is _only used for the function signature_ and we have example documentation for that in several places, including here on this and at the Rcpp Gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimally complete answer.  In the function body you can adjust your tests according to your needs, this is just a placeholder example.

##### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List foo(Rcpp::NumericVector v) {

    // we just us a random vector here to determine: if positive
    // we inject a string, if negative NULL

    const std::string mystring = "helloworld";  // if positive

    int n = v.size();
    Rcpp::List z(n);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (v[i] < 0) {
            z[i] = mystring;
        } else {
            z[i] = R_NilValue;
        }
    }

    return z;
}

/*** R
set.seed(123)
foo(rnorm(3)))
set.seed(123456)
foo(rnorm(3))
*/
```

##### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/70601602/answer.cpp")

> set.seed(123)

> foo(rnorm(3))
[[1]]
[1] "helloworld"

[[2]]
[1] "helloworld"

[[3]]
NULL


> set.seed(123456)

> foo(rnorm(3))
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] "helloworld"

[[3]]
[1] "helloworld"

>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! You're entirely correct---I was confused regarding how to work with Rcpp::Nullable. As mentioned, "the helper class Nullable<> is only used for the function signature". Thank you for setting me straight!

Comment: As so often it all makes sense once you think it through -- the C language foreign function interface offered by `SEX{ .Call("functionname", SEXP a, SEXP b, ....)` needs the gymanstics of `Nullable<>` but we do not need it (or use it) elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Dirk is correct above: fundamentally, my misunderstanding was related to confusion regarding `Rcpp::Nullable`.

> the helper class Nullable<> is only used for the function signature

The following ended up working for me:

```
Rcpp::List rcpp_hello_world() {

    // After calculations from external C++ library,
    // the variable 'mystring' will either empty (i.e. "") or populated (e.g. "helloworld")

    std::string mystring = "helloworld";  // string non-empty


    Rcpp::List z = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("myresult") = nullptr);

    if (mystring.empty()) {
        z["myresult"] = R_NilValue;
    } else  {
        z["myresult"] = mystring;
    }
 
    return z ;
}
```